# "+" replaced by " " in json send to server

Tags: ios, json, nsdate, nsurlrequest

```
   NSString *AuthToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                               stringForKey:@"AuthToken"];


        NSString* json =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{'DeviceId':'%@','DeviceType':'iOS','UM_Identifier':'%@','AuthToken':'%@','Query':'all'}", deviceId, userEmail,  AuthToken];


        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jinpAllCustDetails=%@",json];



         NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];



        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

In above code :

- Auth token received from last webservice response is saved in NSUserdefaults, 
  then used for next webservice request.
- So for Eg.

  Send auth token : `z71VxyfVlBxvNKJ01m64a4oKV9lWEv+fFhHxi+7zyRw=`

  But server would receives it as :`z71VxyfVlBxvNKJ01m64a4oKV9lWEv fFhHxi 7zyRw=`

  ie All occurrences of "+" are replaced by " ". So server considers it as an invalid auth token and the webservices request returns a result accordingly.

Help me to fix this, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with a backslash in front of it ?

Comment: YOu didn't urlencode your values, so the when the server DECODES your submission, `+` becomes spaces. You should properly url-encode your data, or at very least, replace `+` -> `%2B`

Comment: @Zil yes, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't valid JSON as strings should be surrounded with `"`.  Create an `NSDictionary` of the values and use `NSJSONSerialization` to create the JSON string, which you know will be valid:

```
NSDictionary *values = @[
    @"DeviceId": deviceId,
    @"DeviceType": @"iOS",
    @"UM_Identifier": userEmail,
    @"AuthToken": authToken,
    @"Query": @"all"
];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:values
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSAssert(jsonData != nil, @"Failed to create JSON data");
NSString jsonString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```